# Flask API security token with curl Python

Tags: python, flask, curl

I am building a Flask server and I want to check for the access key when sending the curl request. Atm I am adding @token_required before every method and this way works good. However if I send a wrong request or something else happens it return "wrong key" or "token is missing". Is there any other way to implement it.

```
def token_required(f):
@wraps(f)
def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
    token = ""
    if 'x-access-token' in request.headers:
        token = request.headers['x-access-token']
    if not token:
        return jsonify({'message':'token is missing'}), 401
    try:
        if token == app.config['SECRET_KEY']:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return jsonify("wrong key"), 401
    except:
        return jsonify({'message':'Token is invalid'}), 401
return decorated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I usually implement jwt authorization. Note that I'm using the `g` global variable to store and share the user object between blueprints. Hope this helps.

```
def require_jwt(f):
"""
Decorator to require JWT token
"""

@wraps(f)
def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        return jsonify({}), 204
    if 'Authorization' not in request.headers or not request.headers[
            'Authorization'].startswith('Bearer '):
        return jsonify({'error': 'Missing authorization header'}), 401
    token = request.headers['Authorization'].split(' ')[1]
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token,
                             current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'],
                             algorithms=['HS256'])
        user: User = User.query.filter_by(id=payload['id']).first()
        if not user:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid token'}), 401
        else:
            g.user = user


    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid token'}), 401
    except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid token'}), 401
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid token'}), 401
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

return decorated_function
```

Comment: How do you send the curl request with -H Authorization:key?

Comment: `Authorization` is an HTTP header just like like `Content-Type` or `Accept`. The `cURL` command could be something like `curl -X POST https://example.com/api/user/me -H "Authorization: Bearer {token...}"`

Comment: See the cURL man page for more details and examples: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html